# Existe alguna forma de reiniciar todos los "scripts" de la pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Mi problema es el siguente.

Tengo un `div#resultado`, el cual contiene una tabla la cual se llena con datos que consumo de un WebService. En dicha tabla hay un botón por cada fila  que activa un modal para modificar los valores de la fila.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" name="btn_Mcontactos" id="btn_Mcontactos" value="{{contactoId}}">
    <img src="public/img/carpeta.png" alt="Ver" style="height:25px; width:25px;" />
</button>
```

Cuando yo inserto un nuevo valor en la tabla, lo que hago es que actualizo el contenido de `div#resultado` (creo la tabla nuevamente via AJAX). El problema es que cuando doy click en el botón de la tabla no pasa nada, me imagino que no se activa el script que muestra el modal.

¿Hay alguna manera de *reiniciar* los scripts sin recargar la página?

**Código: mostrar y llenar modal del contacto a editar**

```
  $("button[name='btn_Mcontactos']").click(function(){
         var valor = $(this).val();
         var txtcontactoId = $("<input type='text' name='txtajax_contactoid' class='loader' />").val(valor);
         var valor2 = $('#txt_Contactos_ProveedorId').val();
         var txtproveedorid = $("<input type='text' name='txtajax_proveedorid' class='loader' />").val(valor2);
         var valor3 = $('#txt_Contactos_ProveedorNombre').val();
         var txtproveedornombre = $("<input type='text' name='txtajax_proveedornombre' class='loader' />").val(valor3);

              $('#frm_ContactosLista').append(txtcontactoId);
              $('#frm_ContactosLista').append(txtproveedorid);
              $('#frm_ContactosLista').append(txtproveedornombre);

              var url = "./webservice/llenarcontactos.php";

              $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url: url,
                  data: $("#frm_ContactosLista").serialize(),
                  success: function(data){
                      $("#Mcontenido1").html(data);
                      $("#Modal_MContactos").modal();

                  }
              });

              return false;
          });
```

**Tabla con el botón**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modal para modificar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `El problema es que cuando doy click en el botón de la tabla no pasa nada, me imagino que no se activa el script que muestra el modal.` = ¿estás seguro que la nueva fila tiene el código que llama la función del modal?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave el error es que añade los listeners a los botones de cada fila en cuando renderiza la tabla por primera vez, sin embargo, cuando vuelve a llenar la tabla por AJAX, los botones que tenían los listeners para el evento fueron eliminados, por ende, los nuevos no tienen ningún listener asociado.

Comment: y como agrego dicho listener . se puede ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cambia el ámbito de tu botón de este:

```
$("button[name='btn_Mcontactos']").click(function(){
```

a este:

```
$("button[name='btn_Mcontactos']").unbind('click');
$(document).on("click","button[name='btn_Mcontactos']", function (event, xhr, settings) {
```

normalmente lo que sucede es que al modificar el DOM ya no es accesible por el map de elementos de jquery, pero jquery tiene esta otro método de script para manejar contenido dinámico. saludos me avisas si te funciona.

También recuerda limpiar el cache de la pagina, ya que los js aveces no se actualizan ..

Comment: Así se haga en vanilla JS no es posible que el botón responda al evento, por la sencilla razón que cuando añades un listener los añades para los elementos que tienes disponibles en el DOM.

Comment: Buenos Dias Francisco Nuñez  Agregue las lineas de codigo  y la funcion  quedo de la siguente manera

Comment: Buenos dias Francisco Agregue Las lineas de codigo pero la consola me muestra el siguente error
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uncaught ReferenceError: click is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?page=verproveedores:15)
    at c (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: @WAG listo me comi las comillas del unbind que hace la referencia al click revisa...

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS CRACK. Solucionado

Comment: @GustavoGarcía es por eso que se debe usar un listener dinamico, y se le llama handler de evento o delegacion de eventos http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Un handler es simplemente una función que será ejecutada cuando se dispare un evento; no tiene que ver con que sea dinámico o no; la delegación de eventos sí que se utiliza para este fin. También se puede hacer con vanilla JS por cierto, y si te apoyas en [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) mcuho mejor ;).

Comment: simplemente no lo he visto con vanilla JS y si el me muestra que su codigo tiene la estructura de jquery le doy el ejemplo que conosco y no le complico la vida. a mi me funciono y a el tambien que es lo importante.

Comment: si hay alternativas es cierto pero no las veo posteada en ninguna respuesta de esta sesion de Q.A